# Aggregate data keeping strings

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
var1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5)
var2 <- c("Place1", "Place2", "Place3", "Place4", "Place5")
var3 <-c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
mydata <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
```

I want to aggregate the dataset by the factors in var1, getting the mean for var3. However, when I do this using the aggregate command:

```
aggregate(mydata, list(mydata$var1), mean)
```

It returns NAs for var2. Ideally, it would return something that looked like this:

```
    var1 var2              var3
    1    Place1            2
    2    Place2 + Place3   5
    4    Place 4           8
    5    Place 5           10
```

I can't quite figure out how to do this with the aggregate command. I've also tried assigning var1 and var2 from the original dataset to a new dataset, doing the aggregation, then merging it back in, but the merge command puts in multiple values of var1 again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be better off using "data.table" for something like this:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydata)[, list(var2 = paste(var2, collapse = "+"), 
                             var3 = mean(var3)), by = var1]
#    var1          var2 var3
# 1:    1        Place1    2
# 2:    2 Place2+Place3    5
# 3:    4        Place4    8
# 4:    5        Place5   10
```

---

Or "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  summarise(var2 = paste(var2, collapse = "+"), var3 = mean(var3))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# 
#   var1          var2 var3
# 1    1        Place1    2
# 2    2 Place2+Place3    5
# 3    4        Place4    8
# 4    5        Place5   10
```

---

#### Update

Based on your comment, you may want to look at an option like the following...

Here's some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5),
  var2 = c("Place1", "Place2", "Place3", "Place4", "Place5"),
  matrix(sample(5, 20, TRUE), nrow = 5)
)
mydata
#   var1   var2 X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1    1 Place1  2  5  2  3
# 2    2 Place2  2  5  1  4
# 3    2 Place3  3  4  4  5
# 4    4 Place4  5  4  2  2
# 5    5 Place5  2  1  4  4
```

First, we `melt` it, then we "aggregate" using "data.table", then we use `dcast.data.table` to get back to the wide form.

```
dcast.data.table(
  melt(as.data.table(mydata), 
       id.vars = c("var1", "var2"))[, list(
         var2 = paste(var2, collapse = "+"),
         value = mean(value)), by = list(var1, variable)],
  var1 + var2 ~ variable, value.var = "value")
#    var1          var2  X1  X2  X3  X4
# 1:    1        Place1 2.0 5.0 2.0 3.0
# 2:    2 Place2+Place3 2.5 4.5 2.5 4.5
# 3:    4        Place4 5.0 4.0 2.0 2.0
# 4:    5        Place5 2.0 1.0 4.0 4.0
```

---

Here's an equivalent approach to the update using "dplyr" and "tidyr":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>%
  gather(var, value, X1:X4) %>%
  group_by(var1, var) %>%
  summarise(var2 = paste(var2, collapse = "+"),
            value = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(var, value)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# 
#   var1          var2  X1  X2  X3  X4
# 1    1        Place1 2.0 5.0 2.0 3.0
# 2    2 Place2+Place3 2.5 4.5 2.5 4.5
# 3    4        Place4 5.0 4.0 2.0 2.0
# 4    5        Place5 2.0 1.0 4.0 4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I haven't used the data.table package before. In my dataset, there are many "var3"s that I need to take the mean of. Is there an easier way to do this than type them all out?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> a1 = aggregate(var2~var1, data=mydata, paste, collapse='+')
> a2 = aggregate(var3~var1, data=mydata, mean)
> merge(a1, a2)
  var1          var2 var3
1    1        Place1    2
2    2 Place2+Place3    5
3    4        Place4    8
4    5        Place5   10
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `aggregate` is used when you want to perform the same operation on all columns but here we want one operation on `var2` and a different one on `var3` (or perhaps the rest).  Thus we need to use `aggregate` twice.   We could have written the second `aggregate` as `aggregate(var3 ~ var2, mydata, mean)[-1]` but we used the form shown so that if there are additional variables after `var3` they will each be averaged as well.  The `[-1]` is due to the fact that both `aggregate` expressions produce a `var1` column and we only need one of them.

```
cbind(aggregate(var2 ~ var1, mydata, toString), 
      aggregate(. ~ var1, mydata[-2], mean)[-1] 
)
```

giving:

```
  var1           var2 var3 var4
1    1         Place1    2    2
2    2 Place2, Place3    5    5
3    4         Place4    8    8
4    5         Place5   10   10
```

**2)** `You could also consider using one of a number of packages for this sort of thing. For
example:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select var1, group_concat(var2) var2, avg(var3) var3 
       from mydata group by var1")

  var1          var2 var3
1    1        Place1    2
2    2 Place2,Place3    5
3    4        Place4    8
4    5        Place5   10
```

or if all variables after the first two are to averaged, each separately:

```
nms <- tail(names(mydata), -2)
Names <- toString(sprintf("avg(%s) '%s'", nms, nms))
fn$sqldf("select var1, group_concat(var2) var2, $Names from mydata group by var1")
```

**Update** Added second solution and simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget tapply.

```
data.frame(var1 = unique(var1),
           var2 = tapply(var2,var1,paste,collapse = ' + '),
           var3 = tapply(var3,var1,mean))
```

Using the mydata data.frame is optional.

For multiple variables in the same data.frame as requested in a comment:

```
data.frame(var1 = unique(mydata$var1),
           var2 = tapply(mydata$var2,mydata$var1,paste,collapse = ' + '),
           apply(mydata[,3:5],MARGIN = 2,function(x){
             tapply(x,mydata$var1,mean)
           }))
```

Where [ ,3:5] can be used however you need to get the correct columns, like grep.